# app.Screenshot("") command runs for ever in xamarin UI test

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.uitest

In my automation using Xamarin UI test, the screenshot command is running endlessly. It is taking screen shot and storing it in default folder but the command never ends in execution. I enabled local screenshot capability on app object.

Code :

```
       [Test]
       [Category("XXX")]

       public async void Test1()
       {

        // Click on button
        app.Tap(x => x.Class("RelativeLayout"));

        // Click button
        app.Tap(x => x.Class("RelativeLayout"));
        await Task.Delay(3000);

        // Click button
        app.Tap(x => x.Text("Viewpoints"));

        // Select Geometry
        app.Tap(x => x.Text("Geometry"));

        await Task.Delay(10000);

        // screen shot
        app.Screenshot("");
    }
```

Comment: Have you enabled local screenshots per https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/testcloud/uitest/cheatsheet/#Enable_Screenshots_Locally ? Are you on the latest version of Xamarin.UITest (2.0.9)?

Comment: yes I enabled. And yes I am using Xamarin.UITest 2.0.9, NUnit - 2.6.4

Comment: It sounds like it may be a bug then; you may want to log into testcloud.xamarin.com, and use the support link to reach out there. If you can, I'd recommend sharing with support a reproducible sample via a filesharing link like from OneDrive or Dropbox etc.

Answer (score 0):

The **async** keyword is causing the problem.

**Remove async** from you test definition and Screenshots will work fine :

```
   [Test]
   [Category("XXX")]
   public void Test1()
   {
       //....

       Task.Delay(3000).Wait();

       //...
   }
```